# How to create a column of random numbers in dataframe based on the unique values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a column "Cust Rank" which will give me random numbers which should be based on other column "Creator".
The only catch here is that the random Numbers should be same for the same Creators.

I have tried the below code but it's not working as expected.

```
df["Cust Rank"] = df.groupby(["Creator"]).transform(pd.Series([np.random.randint(1,5)]))
```

This is how I want it to be:

| Creator | Cust Rank |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) Creators, [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) (or [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the items), then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values:

```
import random
s = list(df['Creator'].unique())
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(random.sample(s, len(s)), start=1)}

df['Cust Rank'] = df['Creator'].map(d)
```

Another option with pandas's [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = df['Creator'].sample(frac=1)
df['Cust Rank'] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0]+1, index=s.index)
```

Output:

```
  Creator  Cust Rank
0       A          2
1       A          2
2       B          3
3       C          1
4       C          1
```

Comment: Thank you . This helped me. 
But what should be changed if i want to assign ranks to the creator not the length of the unique values in creator but  1-5.
Given that ranks can be duplicated for different creator names, but same names should have the same rank

Comment: Then it's not really a rank? Or do you have to rank the string on their lexicographic order (`df['Creator'].rank(method='dense')`)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The rank is not a Dictionary rank but kind of like a Quantitative value given to a person based on his priority in my process.
So multiple people can have the same quantitative value which id like to call as rank

Comment: Then `df['Rank'] = pd.factorize(df['Creator'])[0]`? but it's not "*quantitative*", it doesn't quantify anything. It's just a category.

Comment: True. But i just want to categorize the column creator to 1-5. Not more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Get unique values by [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabltransfe/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html), then apply [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) and map by dictionary created by `zip` in [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
u = df["Creator Cust"].unique()
np.random.shuffle(u)
 
df["Cust Rank"] = df["Creator Cust"].map(dict(zip(u, np.arange(1,len(u)+1))))
print (df)
  Creator Cust  Rank  Cust Rank
0            A     1          2
1            A     1          2
2            B     2          1
3            C     3          3
4            C     3          3
```